# In Tab bar to go an other fragment in the same tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am using FragmentAcitvity in my Tab Bar .
I am able to load a new fragment on tab changed.
But i have a problem Because i have many activties in one tab.
for example i have 2 tabs :
Tab1 , Tab2. and i have in 
Tab1 : activityA-->activityB---ActivityC
and 
Tab2: activityF
how i can achieve this.

my code is here.
Main Class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
Context context=this;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(context, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("Records").setIndicator("")), ActiovityA.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("tab2"),acitvityf.class, null);


    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}
```

my acitvityA is here
    public class acitvityA extends Fragment {

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acitvitya_xml, container, false);
        return v;
    }  

}
```

myactivityB is

```
 public class acitvityb extends Fragment {

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.acitvityb_xml, container, false);
        return v;
    }  

}
```

how i can solve this ?what is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do a little bit of homework yourself, but i could give you a hint that could help you.

You have the tabs set well. What you could do is, When the transition from Activity1 to 2 takes place, hide the last fragment from the stack, and then show the Activity 2 fragment in tab one (here you will push the fragment into the stack and show it). Maintain a stack of the fragments you are using, and compare an instance of which fragment has been pushed or popped from the stack to bring back the correct fragment.

Its a combination of fragment transactions add, hide, and stack push and pop.

Stack is needed for back press events.

Hope that helps.